# How to verify the validity of reinterpret_cast at compile time

Tags: c++

I need a way to verify **during compile time** that upcast/downcast of a pointer to another class (either derived or base) does not change the pointer value. That is, the cast is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`.

To be concrete, the scenario is the following: I have a `Base` class and a `Derived` class (obviously derived from `Base`). There is also a template `Wrapper` class that consists of a pointer to the class specified as a template parameter.

```
class Base
{
    // ...
};

class Derived
    :public Base
{
    // ...
};

template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
    T* m_pObj;
    // ...
};
```

In some situations I have a variable of type `Wrapper<Derived>`, and I'd like to call a function that receives a (const) reference ro `Wrapper<Base>`. Obviously there is no automatic cast here, `Wrapper<Derived>` is not derived from `Wrapper<Base>`.

```
void SomeFunc(const Wrapper<Base>&);

Wrapper<Derived> myWrapper;
// ...

SomeFunc(myWrapper); // compilation error here
```

There are ways to handle this situation within the scope of the standard C++. Like this for example:

```
Derived* pDerived = myWrapper.Detach();

Wrapper<Base> myBaseWrapper;
myBaseWrapper.Attach(pDerived);

SomeFunc(myBaseWrapper);

myBaseWrapper.Detach();
myWrapper.Attach(pDerived);
```

But I don't like this. Not only this demands an awkward syntax, but it also produces an extra code, because `Wrapper` has a non-trivial d'tor (as you may guessed), and I'm using exception handling. OTOH if the pointer to `Base` and `Derived` are the same (like in this example, since there's no multiple inheritance) - one may just cast `myWrapper` to the needed type and call `SomeFunc`, and it will work!

Hence I've added the following to `Wrapper`:

```
template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
    T* m_pObj;
    // ...

    typedef T WrappedType;


    template <class TT>
    TT& DownCast()
    {
        const TT::WrappedType* p = m_pObj; // Ensures GuardType indeed inherits from TT::WrappedType

        // The following will crash/fail if the cast between the types is not equivalent to reinterpret_cast
        ASSERT(PBYTE((WrappedType*)(1)) == PBYTE((TT::WrappedType*)(WrappedType*)(1)));

        return (TT&) *this; // brute-force case
    }

    template <class TT> operator const Wrapper<TT>& () const
    {
        return DownCast<Wrapper<TT> >();
    }
};


Wrapper<Derived> myWrapper;
// ...

// Now the following compiles and works:
SomeFunc(myWrapper);
```

The problem is that in some cases the brute-force cast is not valid. For instance in this case:

```
class Base
{
    // ...
};

class Derived
    :public AnotherBase
    ,public Base
{
    // ...
};
```

Here the value of the pointer to `Base` differs from `Derived`. Hence `Wrapper<Derived>` is not equivalent to `Wrapper<Base>`.

I'd like to detect and prevent attempts of such an invalid downcast. I've added the verification (as you may see), but it works in **run-time**. That is, the code would compile and run, and during the runtime there'll be a crash (or a failed assertion) in debug build.

This is fine, but I'd like to catch this during compile time and fail the build. A sort of a STATIC_ASSERT.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe using a `static_cast` here `return (TT&) *this; // brute-force case` instead of the c-cast might help, the c-cast might be doing reinterpret_cast which indeed would break everything. If both class share inheritance, the compiler should make the pointers point to the right places with `static_cast`.

Comment: @RedX: in this specific place this is equivalent to `static_cast`, since the rwo classes `Wrapper<Base>` and `Wrapped<Derived>` are not related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

Long answer:

There is limited introspection available at compilation time, and you can for example (using function overload resolution) detects if a class B is an accessible base class of another class D.

However that's about it.

The Standard does not require full introspection, and notably:

- you cannot list the (direct) base classes of a class
- you cannot know whether a class has only one or several base classes
- you cannot even know if a base class is the first base or not

And of course, there is the issue that the object layout is more or less unspecified, anyway (though C++11 adds the ability to distinguish between trivial layout and class with virtual methods if I remember correctly, which helps a bit here!)

Using Clang, and its AST inspection capabilities, I think you could write a dedicated checker, but this seems quite complicated, and is of course totally non-portable.

Therefore, despite your bold claim *P.S. Please don't reply with "why do you want to do this" or "this is against the standard". I know what what all this for, and I have my reasons to do this.*, you will have to adapt your ways.

Of course, if we were given a broader picture of your usage of this class, we might be able to pool our brains together and help you figure a better solution.

---

How to implement a similar system ?

I would propose, first, a simple solution:

- `Wrapper<T>` is the owner class, non-copyable, non-convertible
- `WrapperRef<U>` implements a proxy over an existing `Wrapper<T>` (as long as `T*` is convertible to `U*`) and provide the conversions facilities.

We will use the fact that all pointers to be manipulated inherit from `UnkDisposable` (this is a crucial information!)

Code:

```
namespace details {
  struct WrapperDeleter {
    void operator()(UnkDisposable* u) { if (u) { u->Release(); } }
  };


  typedef std::unique_ptr<UnkDisposable, WrapperDeleter> WrapperImpl;
}

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
  Wrapper(): _data() {}

  Wrapper(T* t): _data(t) {}

  Wrapper(Wrapper&& right): _data() {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_data, right._data);
  }

  Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper&& right) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_data, right._data);
    return *this;
  }

  T* Get() const { return static_cast<T*>(_data.get()); }

  void Attach(T* t) { _data.reset(t); }
  void Detach() { _data.release(); }

private:
  WrapperImpl _data;
}; // class Wrapper<T>
```

Now that we laid down the foundations, we can make our adaptive proxy. Because we will only manipulate everything through `WrapperImpl`, we ensure the type-safety (and the meaningful-ness of our `static_cast<T*>`) by checking conversions through `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` in the template constructors:

```
template <typename T>
class WrapperRef {
public:
  template <typename U>
  WrapperRef(Wrapper<U>& w,
    std::enable_if_c< std::is_base_of<T, U> >::value* = 0):
    _ref(w._data) {}

  // Regular
  WrapperRef(WrapperRef&& right): _ref(right._ref) {}
  WrapperRef(WrapperRef const& right): _ref(right._ref) {}

  WrapperRef& operator=(WrapperRef right) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_ref, right._ref);
    return *this;
  }

  // template
  template <typename U>
  WrapperRef(WrapperRef<U>&& right,
    std::enable_if_c< std::is_base_of<T, U> >::value* = 0):
    _ref(right._ref) {}

  template <typename U>
  WrapperRef(WrapperRef<U> const& right,
    std::enable_if_c< std::is_base_of<T, U> >::value* = 0):
    _ref(right._ref) {}

  T* Get() const { return static_cast<T*>(_ref.get()); }

  void Detach() { _ref.release(); }

private:
  WrapperImpl& _ref;
}; // class WrapperRef<T>
```

It might be tweaked according to your needs, for example you could remove the ability to Copy and Move the `WrapperRef` class to avoid situation where it point to a no longer valid `Wrapper`.

On the other hand, you could also enrich this using a `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` approach in order to be able to copy and move the wrapper and still guarantee the availability (but beware of memory leaks).

*Note: it is intentional that `WrapperRef` does not provide an `Attach` method, such a method cannot be used with a base class. Otherwise with both `Apple` and `Banana` deriving from `Fruit`, you could attach a `Banana` through a `WrapperRef<Fruit>` even though the original `Wrapper<T>` was a `Wrapper<Apple>`...*

*Note: this is easy because of the common `UnkDisposable` base class! This is what gives us a common denominator (`WrapperImpl`).*

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I thought about a compile-time check, some sort of an expression that may be calculated at compile time and subjected to a `STATIC_ASSERT` macro (hope you're familiar with this technique). BTW the expression that I used `PBYTE((WrappedType*)(1)) == PBYTE((TT::WrappedType*)(WrappedType*)(1))` **may** theoreticall be calculated at compile time. I'm sure in release build with optimizations enabled the compiler will substitute the known result. However the compiler I use (msvc) doesn't allow this.

Comment: Broader picture. I have a base interface `UnkDisposable` which has a `virtual Release() = 0;`. The `Wrapper` is a RAII wrapper that wraps the pointer to such an object and makes sure `Release` is called when necessary. `Wrapper` is a template class that wraps any class that inherits from `UnkDisposable`. Classes implement `UnkDisposable` in a different manner: some delete the object immediately, whereas others implement reference-counting (they also have `AddRef`). continued...

Comment: There's a function that takes some parameters and is responsible to initiate an asynchronous operation. If this succeeds - it should take the ownership of the appropriate allocated resources. There's an interface `CompletionHandler` inherited from `UnkDisposable`, which adds the relevant completion/error handler methods. The function takes `Wrapper<CompletionHandler>&` as a parameter. If everything is ok - it detaches the allocated object from the given wrapper and takes the ownership of it (attaches it to its internal wrapper). continued...

Comment: There's a class `MyCompletionHandler` derived from `CompletionHandler`. It's allocated, initialized, and passed to the function. I want to be able to do this: `Wrapper<MyCompletionHandler> pHandler(new MyCompletionHandler);` and then use it as an argument where `Wrapper<CompletionHandler>` or `Wrapper<UnkDisposable>` is expected

Comment: @valdo: is there any reason you can't use more conventional destructor-based RAII (smart pointers in particular), rather than trying to emulate C#?

Comment: `Wrapper` is actually a "destructor-based RAII"

Comment: This problem exists with standard smart pointers too. It may be solved if objects support reference-counting, then assignment/copy c'tor for smart pointers is ok, then one may receive the needed wrapper **by value**. But I don't want to do this: (1) I don't want to add reference counting to all the objects, it's not really needed. Only some of them need to be referenced in several places, those will have non-trivial implementation of `Release`. (2) Anyway extra `AddRef/Release` is a waste. What I need is `Attach/Detach`

Comment: @valdo: thanks for the detailed background, I may have a simple solution (imperfect, obviously :p) that could help.

Comment: @valdo: I have updated the answer with a possible solution (took me longer than I first thought :p), this should be suitable for your problem.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for taking the time and providing the code. So your solution is: (1) Enable copy c'tor and assignment operator by using "move" semantix. That is, assignment steals the ownership. (2) add an appropriate cast operator to `WrapperRef` that will return by value the wrapper of the needed type. This makes sense. continued...

Comment: However there are drawbacks too. (1) I'm pretty sure there will be some extra code generated, you're creating a temporary obj with non-trivial d'tor (perhaps this is insignificant). (2) I don't like the idea of auto-move-semantics. By such you may loose the object without even noticing it! Suppose you have a function that receives `WrapperRef<Derived>&`, and eventually decides not to take the ownership of the object. But this is too late: the object is already stolen by the temporary, and after the function call it will be deleted!

Comment: @valdo: There is no automatic stealing involved here, the `WrapperRef<T>` is purposely lightweight and, as the name implies, refer to a `Wrapper<>` object. The `Wrapper` owns the resource and cannot be copied (it behaves like `std::unique_ptr`). The `WrapperRef` refer to a `Wrapper`, in fact, it emulates a  `Wrapper<T>&` that would allow derived to base conversion on the template parameter. There is no specific action on construction or destruction for `WrapperRef<T>`, no allocating resources, no releasing either. The lifetime is solely controlled by `Wrapper<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that  `WrapperRef` owns just a *reference* to `WrapperImpl`. Now I see your point: the "actual" wrapper (responsible for cleanup) will hold the pointer `UnkDisposable`. This is the "meat". Next you declare a `Wrapper<T>` that will on-demand cast it to the needed type. And then you declare lightweight `WrapperRef<T>` that can be cast by value to whatever type consistent with inheritance at zero price. I like this. continued...

Comment: However unfortunately in most of the cases this won't solve the problem. As long as all the interfaces inherit from `UnkDisposable` just once, whereas it's the first class in the hierarchy - there's no problem with both approaches (mine and yours). My approach is ok since pointers to all the interfaces are equal, and yours is ok because `UnkDisposable` is inherited only once, and the cast is unambiguous. Now imagine you've created a complex object that inherits (non-virtually) two interfaces, `Derived1` and `Derived2', both derived from `UnkDisposable`. continued...

Comment: In my approach downcast to `Derived1` is ok, however downcast to `Derived2` is invalid. In your approach however it will be impossible to work with `Wrapper<DerivedBoth>` because casting from `UnkDisposable` to it will be ambiguous, your `Get` method won't compile. You'll have to incorporate the correct casting route into your `Wrapper`. Same with `WrapperRef<DerivedBoth>`

Comment: @valdo: Exact, I had not considered `virtual` inheritance and diamond shapes. This can be solved by introducing traits, to customize the casting: the "by-default" trait is just a simple `static_cast` and you can specialize it for more complicated behaviors (`dynamic_cast` for virtual inheritance, custom paths for diamond shapes, mix of the two, etc...)